# PHP stripe looping twice

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm using the [Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api). I'm creating a [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create) and then assigning that customer to a [subscription](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create). For some reason the while loop is looping twice. It's creating two of the same customers into Stripe and also inserting two of the same into the *users_subscription* table. Any reason why this is doing this?

---

**Duplicated twice into Stripe backend**
[image]

**Duplicated twice into database table "users_subscription"**
[image]

**Here is the code**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"])) {
    header("Location: ../login.php");
    exit();
}

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('XXXXX');
// Get the token from the JS script

// Create connection
include '../db.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users JOIN users_data ON users.id = users_data.member_id WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'";

$result = $con->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $user_username = $row["username"];
        $user_email = $row["email"];
        $first_name = $row["first_name"];
        $last_name = $row["last_name"];
        $date_subscription_creation = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        try {
            
            $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

            // Create a Customer
            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "name" => $first_name . ' ' . $last_name,
                "email" => $user_email,
                "source" => $token,
            ));

            // Create a Subscription for that Customer
            $Subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'items' => [[
                    'price' => 'price_1MmiSbHB5OMGqmnSedfYDOol',
                ]]
            ]);


            // Add subscription information to database users_subscription
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users_subscription (username, first_name, last_name, email, stripe_subscription_id, stripe_customer_id, stripe_plan_id, created, status)
        VALUES ('$user_username', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$user_email', '', '$customer->id', 'price_1MmiSbHB5OMGqmnSedfYDOol', '$date_subscription_creation', 'active')";

            if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                // End Stripe things
                print_r($Subscription);
            } else { 
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
            }
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
            echo '<div class="container">';
            echo '<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">ERROR:</h5>';
            echo '<p class="card-text">';

            // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
            echo 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '\n';
            echo 'Type is:' . $e->getError()->type . '\n';
            echo 'Code is:' . $e->getError()->code . '\n';
            // param is '' in this case
            echo 'Param is:' . $e->getError()->param . '\n';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo 'Message is: ' . $e->getError()->message . '\n';
            
            echo '</p>
          
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>';
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
            // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
            // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
            // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
            // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
            // Network communication with Stripe failed
        } catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
            // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
            // yourself an email
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
        }

    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably there are multiple records from a same user on `users_data` table so the join operator, extracts multiple rows. You may limit the result to only one row using **group by** or using only the first row or do not loop through the result.

using **top** operator:

```
$sql = "SELECT top 1 * FROM users JOIN users_data ON users.id = users_data.member_id WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION["username"] . "'";
```

Comment: Oh maybe! Let me check. Good idea